# Sending Flex data to SQL as the browser closes (on window.onbeforeunload)

Tags: javascript, sql-server, apache-flex, coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion function which sends analytics called from a Flex sendPageAnalytics() function to a SQL database when the user navigates - this works perfectly.

What I am trying to do is have the Flex application send a bunch of analytics when the user closes their browser, therefore providing information about the last navigation.

I have used an ExternalInterface callback and listener for window.onbeforeunload and a trace statement tells me that this is working fine.

My problem is that when all bundled together, I get as far as tracing out that the sendPageAnalytics() function has been called, but I do not get a sendPageAnalyticsFaultHandler() trace or a sendPageAnalyticsResultHandler() trace, which I do on every other sendPageAnalytics() call.

This suggests to me that the Flash application is unloading from the browser before / while Flex is sending the data to SQL - is there anyway around this?

Comment: Yes. The only place that you can do this is on the html side in the onbeforeunload handler itself (sometimes), and this code will always run, whether the user cancels navigation or not.

Comment: Can't you use AJAX to make these calls to the server instead of using Flex because it seems like, as you mentioned, those handlers are never fired so the browser is closing and you are loosing grasp on your Flex piece.

Answer (score 0):

I have to second that making an AJAX call would be the most reliable way to do this. As long as the analytics data is always ready to be sent, you know the request can be fired off directly in sendPageAnalytics() without the issue where the browser starts the request, but maybe doesn't synchronously complete before it closes.

Seems you can do this and test for the resulting analytics data, or even just look at the logged requests serverside to see if it's functioning.